# 떠들고 다니다 meaning

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrases

The sentence is:

> 벌써 2학년 1학기가 지나 버렸고 더 이상은 기다릴 수 없다고 마음먹자, 갑자기 웬 농구부 주장이 오늘 혜현에게 고백을 하겠다고 공공연히 떠들고 다녔다.

And like, I get what it's saying, but does *떠들고 다니다* mean something specific as a phrase?

I get that he's talking about confessing, but does adding *다니다* to that add anything grammatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it means that he **went around** saying he would confess.

다니다 is one of a few verbs that often gets paired up with another, to link the actions together.  It emphasizes that the person is going around from place to place while doing the action.